# No manual for man command under tmux in OS X

Tags: macos, bash, tmux, manpage

If I use `man` command just in Terminal, it works well.

However, under `tmux`, it will print out **No manual entry** for any command. For example:

```
$man find
No manual entry for find
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `echo $PATH` maybe different

Comment: `$MANPATH` would be the relevant variable.

Comment: $MANPATH is different in `tmux`, change to the default one works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that `$MANPATH` is different under `tmux`. It misses some paths like `/usr/share/man`.

Change `$MANPATH` under `tmux` will work.